# Почему React не подключается по socket.io?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

Есть код на react вида:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
socket.on('connect', (d) => {
  socket.emit('new_connection', document.location.href.split('?')[1].replace(document.location.hash, ''))
})
```

Код node:

```
var app = express() 
var http = require('http').createServer(app)
var io = require('socket.io')(http)

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('new_connection',  () => {
    console.log('ok')
  })
});



http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000')
})
```

Суть в том, что на локалке (на моем пк) все работает, стоит загрузить на сервер, там он не подключается. Путь на Nginx настроил, вместо `'http://localhost:3000'` что только не пробовал писать, и url, и ip машины, соединяться не хочет. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Может дело в https?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте убрать адрес при создании `io()`:

```js
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io(); // Socket.io само определяет, куда подключаться
socket.on('connect', (d) => {
  socket.emit('new_connection', document.location.href.split('?')[1].replace(document.location.hash, ''))
})
```

Надеюсь, это сработает.

Comment: Так тоже пробовал